# How to loop for 3 times in bash script when docker push fails?

Tags: bash, docker, for, exit-status

I have a bash script which simply docker pushes an image:

```
docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest
```

I want to loop for 3 times when this fails. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `for-loop` and `&& break`:

```
for n in {1..3}; do
    docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest && break;
done
```

`break` quits the loop, but only runs when `docker push` succeeded. If `docker push` fails, it will exit with error and the loop will continue.

Comment: Technically, OP wants it to loop three times **when it fails**.  So, shouldn't the loop counter be **4**?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use :

```
for n in {1..4}; do
     if docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest  
     then 
          break;
     fi
done
```

The `then` statement will be entered only if the docker command succeeds.